# Javascript check css whether div display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now, i have a div and i did an inline style, display:none. When the user click a button, it will call a javascript function and change the div display to according value. However, how can i do such check as they kept returning display:none even when in actual, display is block.
Here is my javascript code

```
function unhideDiv(){
var divDOC=document.querySelector('divContent');
var result = document.getComputedStyle(divDOC, '').display;
if(result=='none'){
divDOC.style.display="block";
}
else
{
divDOC.style.display="none";
}

}
```

Here is my html code

```
    <div id="divContent" style="display:none;" >
    </div>
<button onclick="unhideDiv()">Click This </button>
```

Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just use jQuery's `.toggle()`. If you want to do this yourself, use a variable to store the state. In your function, switch the variable, then set the style based on its new value.

Comment: You should open your browser console to check for errors. Also `querySelector('divContent')` should be `querySelector('#divContent')` but since you have jQuery tagged in this question why not just use `toggle()`...?

Comment: If you set the `Element.style.display` to what you want to begin with, you won't have to get a computed style. Or think 0 and 1.

Comment: @PHPglue is there anyway that i can solve this? By default, i want div to be hidden. Upon clicking the button, it will set display as block.

Comment: @QCcccc working with `window.getComputedStyle()` rather than `document.getComputedStyle()` https://jsfiddle.net/r4t1b7ub/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot easier to give the element a class that will hide it, then just toggle the class.

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleHide()">Click This</button>
<div id="divContent" class="hide">div</div>

<script>
  function toggleHide() {
    document.getElementById('divContent').classList.toggle('hide');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're targeting the correct element with your `querySelector` method:

`var divDOC = document.querySelector("#divContent");`

Also, the command to get the computedStyle is `window.getComputedStyle()`

So your code would be something like this:

```
function unhideDiv(){
    var divDOC=document.querySelector('#divContent');
    var result = window.getComputedStyle(divDOC, '').display;
    if(result=='none'){
        divDOC.style.display="block";
    }
    else
    {
        divDOC.style.display="none";
    }
}
```

Comment: You may also wish to add some content inside your div, so that you can see when it is visible and invisible. 
`<div id="divContent" style="display:none;" ><p>Visible</p></div>`

Answer (score 0):

I like this solution:

```js
// external.js
var doc, E; // reuse on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){
  
doc = document;
E = function(id){ // super easy
 return doc.getElementById(id);
}
var bS = E('box').style, d = 1;
E('butt').addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(d){
    bS.display = 'none'; d = 0;
  }
  else{
    bS.display = 'block'; d = 1;
  }
});

});
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
.main{
  width:980px; margin:0 auto;
}
#box{
  width:100px; height:100px; background:orange
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div id='box'>test box</div>
    <input type='button' id='butt' value='change display' />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```